# How to wait for a button to become enabled in a Flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In a Flutter integration test, I want to wait for a button to become enabled before pressing it. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps it's not currently possible, as there's a feature request for it in the Flutter issue tracker: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36405

Answer (score 3):

This function gets you whether a widget is enabled, and you could then wait for it to change state:

```dart
Future<bool> isEnabled(FlutterDriver driver, SerializableFinder widgetFinder) async {
  Map widgetDiagnostics = await driver.getWidgetDiagnostics(widgetFinder);
  return widgetDiagnostics["properties"]
      .firstWhere((property) => property["name"] == 'enabled')["value"];
}
```

**Update:** here's that wait- friend

```dart
Future<void> waitForEnabled(
    FlutterDriver driver, SerializableFinder widgetFinder,
    {Duration timeout,
    Duration interval,
    bool value = true,
    String reason}) async {
  await driver.waitFor(widgetFinder, timeout: timeout);

  timeout ??= Duration(seconds: 5);
  interval ??= Duration(milliseconds: 250);
  var endTime = DateTime.now().add(timeout);

  while (true) {
    if (await isEnabled(driver, widgetFinder) == value) {
      return;
    } else if (DateTime.now().isAfter(endTime)) {
      throw TimeoutException(reason ??
          'widget did not become ${value ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'} within timeout');
    } else {
      await Future.delayed(interval);
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

You can pass `value: false` to have it wait for not-enabled

Comment: As flutter driver is migrated to integration driver, how this can be handled? https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests/migration#example-verifying-a-widget-is-displayed